# Bitwise - Why 0 & 1 !== 1 & 1 return false in VSCode/Leetcode?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I was writing an algorithm to compare how many bits are different between 2 numbers using this function

```js
 var hammingDistance = function(x, y) {
  let result = 0;
  while (x !== 0 || y !== 0) {
    // This line is incorrect
    if (x & 1 !== y & 1) result++;
    x = x >> 1;
    y = y >> 1;
  }
  return result;
};
```

But my result is always `1` less than the correct answer, and it turns our my function is wrong when comparing the left most digit, such as `0011` and `0100`. It returns 2 instead of 3.

[https://i.imgur.com/P46RyZr.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXZaR.png)

I can use `XOR` instead of `!==` to get the correct answer. But I'm wondering why?

Comment: This can also be written `let popCount = (n) => { let c = 0; for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) { c += n & 1; n >>>= 1; } return c; };` and `let hammingDistance = (x, y) => popCount(x ^ y);`, just in case that comes in handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that [`!==` has a higher precedence than `&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table). So your condition is actually `(x & (1 !== y)) & 1`. Use explicit grouping instead:

```
if ((x & 1) !== (y & 1)) result++;
```

It works with `^` because that has a lower precedence than `&`.

Comment: Wow thanks! I didn't know that before. Thanks again for your quick reply.